# Is the light that is created on the first day the sun?

Tags: creation

I am in the process of doing a thorough read and examination of the bible in chronological order for the new year and was pondering if the light God created in Gen. 1:3 was the same light given by the sun created in Gen. 1:16. Genesis 1:3 quotes "And God said 'Let there be light,' and there was light." giving evening and morning to the first day, while Gen. 1:16 explains "God made two great lights-the greater light to govern the day and the lesser light to govern the night"(NIV) clearly referring to the sun and moon, but if the sun was created on the 4th day then what was the light made on the 1st? I know the bible has a tendency to jump back and forth given that later on it explains the creation of man and women, then goes back to the creation of Adam before Eve in Gen. 2:7, so is this what is happening in Gen. 1:3 and Gen. 1:16?

Comment: Hello and welcome to this site! Thank you for asking this interesting question - the good news (I hope) is that it's already been covered here: [What was the light of the first day of creation?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15564/what-was-the-light-of-the-first-day-of-creation) You can use the search facility (box in the top right) to help find other questions and answers; I hope you'll stick around to ask and answer some more.

Comment: Related: [Was God living in darkness before the creation of light?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19192/was-god-living-in-darkness-before-the-creation-of-light)

Comment: I think these arguments make no sense because Genesis is entirely  a metaphorical visualization of the world, nor less nor more.

Comment: The first light that was created was energy in line with most theories about how the universe came into being. You need to know a little about science to understand what happened and thiss is not the site to explain it but it was not the sun that was created.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider So... no one in Genesis is a real person?  Abraham?  Isaac?  Jacob?  Joseph?  No one?  All metaphors?

Comment: @Narnian, yes, I think it is so, there are no historical evidences, but I don't exclude that some stories narrating those characters are inspired from plausible situations.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider So, where in the genealogy of Jesus back to Adam do you think it goes from real people to fictional people?  Or do you believe Jesus is a myth as well?

Comment: @Narnian, I'm not an expert, and so I cannot respond precisely to the first question, but I think it is plausible that Jesus existed, even if I would exclude that he was the natural Son of God. Rather I'm inclined to think that he was the carnal son of Joseph and Mary and that he had a 'special' relation with God in the sense that he had the ability to 'hear' the Word of God. Sorry for my sloppy English, I hope you understand what I want to mean.

Comment: @ James T, Thanks for the link helped with the answer. I hope to ask many more in depth questions that come up in my studies.